# Is there a version of pug that's just an HTML preprocessor and not a JS creator?

Tags: javascript, pug, svelte

I'm getting into Svelte, which is awesome, but because svelte and pug both do similar things with very different syntaxes with regards to JS-html integration, and they don't play as well together as I'd like.

There's some preprocess projects on git, but the caveats and syntaxes are weird and uncomfortable (just use `!=` instead of `=` to designate equals in attributes, etc.).

I'm hoping that there might be a subset of pug that just produces HTML output instead of all of the JS functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "JS creator" and "all of the JS functionality"?

Comment: The output of pug is meant to be a js function (as I understand it) and we hijack part of that to do preprocessing. It's also meant to allow advanced templating functionality to html, both of which svelte does for free, so neither of which we need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459938/is-there-a-way-to-use-pugjs-in-svelte-components